# Fetching data from Symfony Doctrine DB

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have just started my first symfony project and im a little bit confused.

I would like to query database for Shelfs which have no products on them.
I have come up with such sql query which seems to work:

```
select distinct she.id shelf_id,rac.id rack_id , row.id row_id, war.id warehouse_id from shelfs she
left join products pro on she.id = pro.warehouse_id
left join racks rac on she.rack_id=rac.id
left join rows row on rac.row_id = row.id
left join warehouses war on row.warehouse_id = war.id
where she.id not in (select shelf_id from products);
```

But i got no idea how to translate it to dql.

I have tried to write such function in Repository:

```
    {

        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();


        $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
            'SELECT distinct she
            FROM App\Entity\Shelfs she
            JOIN App\Entity\Racks rac
            JOIN App\Entity\Rows row
            JOIN App\Entity\Warehouses war
            WHERE she NOT IN (SELECT prod FROM App\Entity\Products prod)
            ');
        return $query->getResult();

    }
```

That is partialy working as at first it showed the exact values that sql query did.
For example 3 Shelf id with out products on them.
But when I added product to one of those shelf it still shows that 3 are empty.

Thats my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Products::class);
        $product = $repository->find(76); // that's for testing and it is refreshing

        $warehousesRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Warehouses::class);

        $freespace = $warehousesRepository->findempty(); // that is not refreshing


        return $this->render('base.html.twig', [
            'selected_view' => 'pages/findPlace.html.twig',
            'product' => $product,
            'freespace' => $freespace

        ]);
    }
```

Here is my Products Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductsRepository")
 */
class Products
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $barcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Warehouses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="warehouse_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $warehouse_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rows")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="row_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $row_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Racks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rack_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $rack_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shelfs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shelf_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $shelf_id;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getBarcode(): ?int
    {
        return $this->barcode;
    }

    public function setBarcode(int $barcode): self
    {
        $this->barcode = $barcode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantity(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): self
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWarehouseId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->warehouse_id;
    }

    public function setWarehouseId(int $warehouse_id): self
    {
        $this->warehouse_id = $warehouse_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->row_id;
    }

    public function setRowId(int $row_id): self
    {
        $this->row_id = $row_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRackId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->rack_id;
    }

    public function setRackId(int $rack_id): self
    {
        $this->rack_id = $rack_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShelfId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->shelf_id;
    }

    public function setShelfId(int $shelf_id): self
    {
        $this->shelf_id = $shelf_id;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I tried to make relations after creating entities by adding:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Warehouses")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="warehouse_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```

but that didn't work so i guess i need to redo my entities and specify relations in the wizzard.

I have made relations using sql:

```
ALTER TABLE shelfs ADD FOREIGN KEY (rack_id) REFERENCES racks(id);
        ALTER TABLE racks ADD FOREIGN KEY (row_id) REFERENCES rows(id);
        ALTER TABLE rows ADD FOREIGN KEY (warehouse_id) REFERENCES warehouses(id);
        ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY (warehouse_id) REFERENCES warehouses(id);
        ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY (rack_id) REFERENCES racks(id);
        ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY (row_id) REFERENCES rows(id);
        ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY (shelf_id) REFERENCES shelfs(id);
        ALTER TABLE order_items ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id);
        ALTER TABLE order_items ADD FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id);
        ALTER TABLE orders ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id);
```

It should look something like this:

[image: DB Diagram]

I feel like i got lost in the process somewhere.

I got no idea what's happening and i cannot find anything related in symfony documentation.

Comment: please post your entity code so we can determine the associations. When using doctrine you would use the associated relationships between the entities like `JOIN she.racks AS rac`  and `JOIN racks.rows AS row`. Otherwise when specifying the entity namespace, you would specify a join clause `JOIN App\Entity\Racks AS rac WITH she.rackId = rac.id`

Comment: As for tutorials, SO is not really appropriate to ask for such things. However SymfonyCasts is a great resource.

Comment: You can use SQL with Doctrine with [Native Queries](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html) and ResultSetMapper, if that helps. Also, you might want to rethink your models. Since the price is attached to products, but not order items changing a product's price will (retroactively) change the price of order items leading to wrong orders.

Comment: agreed, ordered items price and name at least should be static entries to avoid the relationship being updated when the related `product` is changed. Symfony is just a framework that allows you to utilize Doctrine ORM to map your database with. The ORM is meant specifically for business logic, as a means to be more convenient. For reporting purposes stick to native SQL queries. As for a tutorial go through the [Doctrine tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine)

Comment: You only need to specify the `ORM\JoinColumn` and not also the `ORM\Column`, doctrine will read the annotations for the `referencedColumnName` entity property. It is also encouraged to map out your entities and their relationships first and then execute the [`doctrine:schema:update`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema) command *(or use doctrine migrations)* to create the table structure in your database.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $sel = $this->createQueryBuilder('prod') // FROM App\Entity\Products prod
        ->select('prod')
        // ->from('App\Entity\Products', 'prod'); // FROM App\Entity\Products prod
    ;


    $res = $this->createQueryBuilder('she') // FROM App\Entity\Shelfs she
        ->select('DISTINCT she')
        // ->from('App\Entity\Shelfs', 'she')  // FROM App\Entity\Shelfs she
        ->leftJoin('she.rac', 'rac')
        ->leftJoin('she.row', 'row')
        ->leftJoin('she.war', 'war')
        ->andWhere('she NOT IN :(sel)')->setParameter('sel', $sel->getQuery()->getResult());
        ;

    return $res->getQuery()->getResult();
```